# What do off-diagonals in density matrix represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator

I am having trouble understanding what off diagonal elememts of a density matrix represent. I know that it tells you the coherence but i dont undetstand why. Like in case of diagonal elements it tells you the probability of finding the system in some state because the diagonal terms are the product of the complex number (associated with the state) times its conjugate which gives the probability, but i dot understand the logic behind saying off-diagonal terms tell us coherence

Comment: Thank you ,well i still dont understand how we can infer off diagonal terms say anything about coherence, Think of it this way,how someone who knew nothing about density matrix realised that off diognal term tell us about coherence

Comment: I don't understand, you need to talk about density matrix if you want to discuss its off-diagonal terms. Why would someone be bothered by them if they knew nothing about density matrix, they'd simply not know anything about the off-diagonal terms either. :/

Comment: thats just a scenario i thought up,the question is while i know that off diagonal tells about the coherence i what to know what logic or reasoning leads to this